# Centrar imagen verticalmente, dentro de un Carousel Boostrap

Tags: css, carrusel

Tengo un Carousel Boostrap, con 3 imagenes
Las 3 imagenes son las sgtes:
[imagen1](http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/8/8/3/207253.jpg)
[imagen2](http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/e/5/2/207303.jpg)
[imagen3](http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/9/d/3/207328.jpg)
Lo que quiero lograr, es posicionarlas verticalmente dentro de su propia sección,
De modo que quede el auto a la vista, y no la parte superior de la imagen.
Ahora mismo, las imagenes se veen asi:
https://i.gyazo.com/24bf43ad758066f9ceda1eab0728734b.gif

---

### UPDATE#1

He logrado posicionarlas, pero tienen un efecto raro:
[link](https://i.gyazo.com/3653ca6fb7de9f43aab7da12edd57e85.gif) 
Los cambios que hice fueron:

```
.carousel-inner {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-img {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.carousel-inner>.active {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
html, body {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    object-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    clear: both;
    width: 100%;
    height: 16vh;
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 128, 0.1);
    color: gray;
    font-size: 0.5vh;
}

.footerText {
    color: gray;
    font-size: 2vh;
}

.contenedor {
    text-align: center;
    display: contents;
}

.divinput {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inputl {
    width: 50vw;
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    color: gray;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.has-error .help-block {
    color: darkorange;
    background-color: black;
    margin-top: -0.5vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.slogo {
    width: 30px;
}

.tales {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-inner {
    max-height: 200px !important;
}

.carousel-img {
    background-position: center center;
}

.car1{
    background-position: center bottom;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img class="d-block w-100 car1" src="http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/8/8/3/207253.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/e/5/2/207303.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100" src="http://getwallpapers.com/wallpaper/full/9/d/3/207328.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solución que encontré fue la siguiente:

Al elemento que contiene el item, `.carousel-inner`, le damos una posición relativa.
Además de una altura específicada para el tamaño del carousel.
Al elemento hijo, `.carousel-item`, se le coloca una posición absoluta,

```
.carousel-inner {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -40vh;
}
```

https://i.gyazo.com/217a8da37d0d1a59d2044ed3ac77f8e4.gif

Comment: Pasate por el chat y discutimos otra posible solución

Comment: pero taggeame allá XD